# Check if a given mapping is linear or not?

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

> $f:IR_n[X]\rightarrow IR_3[X]$ given by $f(p(X))=p(0)X^2+Dp(0)X^3$

Can you tell me what is the method to check mapping like this.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Please read this text about [how to ask a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since derivation is a linear operation, you have
\begin{eqnarray*}
f((p+q)(X))&=& (p+q)(0) X^2 +D(p+q)(0) X^3\\
&=& (p(0)+q(0)) X^2 +(Dp(0)+Dq(0)) X^3\\
&=& p(0)X^2+q(0) X^2 +Dp(0)X^3 +Dq(0)X^3\\ &=& f(p(X))+ f(q(X))\\
\end{eqnarray*}
for all $p,q \in \mathbb R_n[X]$,  and
\begin{eqnarray*}
f((\alpha \cdot p)(X))&=& (\alpha \cdot p)(0) X^2 +D(\alpha \cdot p)(0) X^3\\
&=& \alpha \cdot p(0) X^2 +\alpha \cdot Dp(0) X^3\\
&=& \alpha \cdot f(p(X)) \\
\end{eqnarray*}
for all $p \in \mathbb R_n[X]$ and $\alpha \in \mathbb R$.